# Prove an apparently true equality

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Is there a clean way to show the following apparently correct equality:
$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X|Y<c)\cdot P(Y<c) 
= \mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\mathbb1_{(Y<c)}\cdot X)$$
where $c$ is a constant, and $P(Y<c)>0, P(Y\geq c)>0, \forall c$.

I believe this is true because of the law of total expectation:
$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X) = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X|Y<c)\cdot P(Y<c) 
+ \mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X|Y\geq c)\cdot P(Y\geq c) $$
and the trivial equality:
$$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X) = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\mathbb1_{(Y<c)}\cdot X) 
+ \mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\mathbb1_{(Y\geq c)}\cdot X)$$

Comment: $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}(X|Y<c)$ : random variable, $ P(Y<c) $: number, 
$ \mathop{\mathbb{E}}(\mathbb1_{(Y<c)}\cdot X)$: number... So random variable = number ? Not for every random variable ....

Comment: I should add that c is a constant. $Y<c$ is an event instead of a random number. So E(X|Y<c) is not a number instead of a random number.

Comment: How you define $E[X|A]$ where $A$ is an event?

Comment: @Zach : ok, I see.

Comment: @Shashi: I think you can define it if $P(A)>0$, since you can define a new probability $P_A(B):=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$ and define an expectation $E[X|A]:= E_{P_A}[X]$....

Comment: @Netchaiev okay, but that was a question for the OP,  Zach.

Comment: @Shashi: yes, you are right. I took the liberty to answer to it because I asked myself this question too few minutes ago, so I felt like to share...

Comment: @Shashi:I define E(X|A) as the expectation of X given A. We can define the conditional cdf of (X given A) as F(x) = P(X<x|A). Since the cdf uniquely defines a probability distribution, E(X|A) is defined as the expectation under the distribution.

Comment: @Netchaiev: Your definition is what I had in mind. Also, let's assume P(Y<c) and P(Y>=c) are always positive for all c. Y being a standard norm r.v. is an example.

Comment: @Zach see my answer, below. Is that the definition you had in mind?

Comment: @Shashi: yes it is. Thank you!!

Comment: @Shashi Please get informed about the field, the one and only definition of $E(X\mid A)$ when $X$ is an integrable random variable and $A$ an event such that $P(A)\ne0$, is $$E(X\mid A)=\frac{E(X\mathbf 1_A)}{P(A)}$$

Comment: @Did its not about being well informed or not. I had reasons to write what I have written below.  First of all I did not read all books, so how could I know what definition gets always used?  Indeed what is meant to prove is what I know as a definition. That is the reason I have asked "How you define $E[X|A] $...?". The OP told me what definition he or she was using,  I was just open for it. Maybe they define it like that in Japan or Argentine or whatever, who knows?

Comment: @Did I'm not saying that I know something about conditional expectation, in fact I'm just studying it nowadays from there and there. But saying that being open for a new definition is being not well informed is another thing. I have seen many times things gets defined in different ways and all of them are equivalent after all. Say closedness of sets, compactness of sets and so on...

Comment: @Did all that aside. Seeing your authority and knowledge from Stackexchange I really start believing you that that is actually the only definition. But do you actually feel that some beginner like me can be open for a new definition or not? And how bad is this new definition after all? Just that question for you.

Comment: @Shashi They define it as I say in Japan, in Argentina, in Russia, in France, everywhere. As you would know if you had followed one or two lectures on the subject. This attitude of "answering" questions one knows nothing about, will never stop to amaze me...

Comment: @Did I have edited the answer. I have sent you a comment where I asked why the definition is used first was so bad, but that comment is deleted (by a mod?) and I don't know why? Don't mind that. I have edited the answer now and I hope now it's okay? Many thanks for your feedback, it made me search for a lot of books. Please keep giving feedback, otherwise, I think, nobody could learn things in this world. I also apologise if it felt like I was fighting strongly for my opinion which all was due to the respect I had for OP's definition. I think both parties are okay now. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm d}\newcommand{\P} {\mathbb P}$
**Edited Version.** As user @Did noted, the first answer was misleading since OP's definition of conditional expectation given event was very unusual. One can be very short answering the question. The thing that needs to be proven follows directly from the definition since the expectation of $X$ given an even $A$ such that $\P(A) >0$ is: $$\E[X\mid A] =\frac{\E[X\mathbf{1}_A]} {\P(A)} $$ Multiplying both sides with $\P(A) $ yields the claim. We did not do anything.

---

**First Version.** WARNING: a very unusual definition is used here. Since I have respect for OP's definition I have decided to leave this answer undeleted. Both definitions seem to be equivalent after all.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be the probability space. So we have $X:(\Omega,\mathcal F)\to(E, \mathcal G)$ where $(E,\mathcal G)$ is a measure space. Let $A$ be an event such that $\mathbb P(A)>0$, then $\mathbb P(\cdot\mid A)$ is a well defined measure. You seem to define:
\begin{align}
\E[X|A]=\int_\Omega X(\omega)\, \d\mathbb P (\omega|A)
\end{align}
As said in the beginning: it is a rare definition, but here you go. One can check that $$\d\mathbb P(\omega|A)=\frac{\mathbf{1}_A}{\mathbb P(A)}\d\mathbb P(\omega)$$ We verify it with simple functions. Let $f(\omega)=\sum_{k=1}^N b_i \mathbf{1}_{B_i}(\omega)$:
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega f(\omega)\d\mathbb P(\omega|A)=\sum_{k=1}^N b_i \mathbb P(B_i|A)=\sum_{k=1}^N b_i \frac{\mathbb P(B_i\cap A)}{\mathbb P(A)}=\int_\Omega \sum_{k=1}^N b_i\frac{\mathbf{1}_{B_i\cap A }(\omega)}{\mathbb P(A)}\,\d\mathbb P(\omega)=\int_\Omega f(\omega)\frac{\mathbf{1}_A}{\mathbb P(A)}\d\mathbb P(\omega)
\end{align}
Since it holds for simple functions it holds for all functions (why?). Now we have:
\begin{align}
\E[X|A]=\int_\Omega X(\omega)\frac{\mathbf{1}_A}{\mathbb P(A)}\d\mathbb P(\omega)=\frac{\E[X\mathbf{1}_A]}{\mathbb P(A)}
\end{align}
A little bit more general result of your statement is proved.